# XDebug without query string

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I am developing PHP project, which is need of URL rewriting. When I use xdebug for debugging, it automatically appends query string to URL. Is there any way to debug without appending query string?

I use netbeans as my IDE. If xdebug can't do that. Suggest any other debugger that works with netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xdebug can do this, with the help of a browser extension. These are listed at http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser-extensions

It is also possible to configure Xdebug to initiate a debugging session for *every* request that is being made. You can do this, by turning on the http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_autostart setting.